# How to Debug GWT projects in MyEclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt, myeclipse

I was working with eclipse to debug the gwt projects. Recently i shifted to MyEclipse to get additional benefits but here i am not able to debug the gwt project in myeclipse. I know how to debug java or j2ee project in myeclipse using Tomcat set up in 'servers' tab. I could not find the way to debug gwt project in myeclipse.

Could you please any suggest me to debug the gwt project in MyEclipse.
Shall i need to include the google plug-in in myeclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to install the Google eclipse plug-in in MyEclipse, to work with GWT projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GWT 2.7 you can use SDBG (http://sdbg.github.io/).